# PowerMock not verifying private calls more than once

Tags: mockito, powermock, powermockito

```
Class to be tested
    public class ClassUnderTest {
    public void functionA() {
        functionB();
        functionC();
    }
    private void functionB() {
    }
    private void functionC() {
    }
}
```

Test Class

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class TestClass {
        @Test
        public void testFunctionA() throws Exception {
            ClassUnderTest classUnderTest = PowerMockito.spy(new ClassUnderTest());
            classUnderTest.functionA();
            PowerMockito.verifyPrivate(classUnderTest).invoke("functionB");
            PowerMockito.verifyPrivate(classUnderTest).invoke("functionC");
        }
    }
```

While executing the test class I'm getting the following error,

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedVerificationException: 
Missing method call for verify(mock) here:
-> at org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.verifyPrivate(PowerMockito.java:312)

Example of correct verification:
    verify(mock).doSomething()

Also, this error might show up because you verify either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
```

If one verification is commented then the  test case works fine.

Comment: Hello @bharanitharan, have you got any solution? i have the same problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add ClassUnderTest in PrepareForTest.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ClassUnderTest.class)
public class TestClass {

@Test
public void testFunctionA() throws Exception {
    ClassUnderTest classUnderTest = PowerMockito.spy(new ClassUnderTest());
    classUnderTest.functionA();

   PowerMockito.verifyPrivate(classUnderTest).invoke("functionB");
   PowerMockito.verifyPrivate(classUnderTest).invoke("functionC");
 }
```

I have just added sysouts in private methods & run the test class.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding two lines of code

```html
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class TestClass {
        @Test
        public void testFunctionA() throws Exception {
            ClassUnderTest classUnderTest = PowerMockito.spy(new ClassUnderTest());
            PowerMockito.doNothing().when(classUnderTest, "functionB");
            PowerMockito.doNothing().when(classUnderTest, "functionC");
            classUnderTest.functionA();
            PowerMockito.verifyPrivate(classUnderTest).invoke("functionB");
            PowerMockito.verifyPrivate(classUnderTest).invoke("functionC");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Another idea: don't do that. Do **not** *verify* private methods. Those methods are *private* for a reason. You should really try to avoid to write tests that have to know that some private method was called.

You see, the idea of *private* is: it is subject to change. A good unit test works with **observing** the behavior of your class - you call public methods with different arguments; and you check the results coming back. Or maybe, you use dependency injection to provide mocked objects to your test class - when your test code needs those other methods to do its job.

But you should really **not** start checking private methods. The point is: those private methods should do something that is observable from the outside. Either they work on the final "return" value; or they change some internal state that might be checked in other ways. In other words: if those *private* methods do not cause any other effect on your class under test - what would be their purpose anyway?!

Comment: I agree to your point that you shouldn't test private methods. But in this case I just need to verify whether the private method has been invoked or not.